# Sum of Legendre function: $ f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}P_n(x), $

Tags: real-analysis, special-functions

I'm currently trying to solve the sum
$$
f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}P_n(x),
$$
where $P_n(x)$ is the Legendre function of order n.

I also named the sum $f(x)$ since I'm the solution will be a function of $x$. The first thing that can be noticed is that the function $f(x)$ is an uneven function.

My first step was to take the derivative of $f(x)$, this then yields that:
$$
f'(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty x^{n}P_n(x)+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}P'_n(x).
$$
Using the generating function
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2hz+h^2}}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty h^nP_n(z)
$$
I'm able to rewrite the first term as:
$$
f'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}P'_n(x).
$$
Now for the second term I'm still stuck, I've been trying a few recursive relations, in the hope to maybe get a first order differential equation for $f(x)$. So far I haven't found the right recursive relation yet.

Now I'm wondering if there is maybe a better approach that I should have taken, or that if there is an easy trick to solve the second term?

After playing with the function in Mathematica I figured out that the most probable solution is
$$
f(x)=\mathrm{arctanh}(x),
$$
this gives me a direction, but still I have no clue for the second term. All help is welcome!

Comment: When I plot the sum of the first 20 terms it looks more like $\arcsin{x}$, and of course, you obtained $f(x)=\arcsin{x}+ \int\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}P'_n(x)$.

Comment: @krvolok, my bad I meant the arctanh. I also considered the arcsin, but it did not fit. Not enough bend and wrong values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let: 
$$f(x) = \sum _{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+1} \, P_{n}(x)}{n+1}$$
As you said:
$$f^{'}(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n} \, P_{n}(x) + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} \, P_{n}^{'}(x)$$
And using the generating function you showed, we get:
$$f^{'}(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1 } \, P_{n}^{'}(x)$$
Now, note that:
$$
{ P }_{ n }(x)'\quad =\quad \frac { \left( n+1 \right) \left( x{ P }_{ n }(x)\quad -\quad { P }_{ n+1 }(x) \right)  }{ 1-{ x }^{ 2 } } 
$$

So we get:
\begin{align}
f^{'}(x) &=\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 1-{ x }^{ 2 } }  } +\sum _{ n=0 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { { x }^{ n+1 } }{ n+1 }  } \frac { \left( n+1 \right) \left( x{ P }_{ n }(x) - { P }_{ n+1 }(x) \right)  }{ 1-{ x }^{ 2 } } \\
&= \frac {1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} + \frac{1}{1-x^{2}} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{x^{n+1} \left(x {P}_{n}(x) - {P}_{n+1}(x) \right)} \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} + \frac{1}{1-x^{2}} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n+2} \left( P_{n}(x) \right) - \frac{1}{1-x^{2}} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n+1} \, P_{n+1}(x) \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} +\frac{x^{2}}{1-x^{2}} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n} \left(P_{n}(x) \right) - \frac{1}{1-x^{2}}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n} \, P_{n}(x) -1 \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} + \frac{x^{2}}{1-x^{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} - \frac{1}{1-x^{2}} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} -1\right) \\ 
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} + \frac{x^{2}-1}{ (1-x^{2}) \, \sqrt{1-x^{2}}} + \frac{1}{1-x^{2}} \\ 
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} + \frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} + \frac{1}{1-x^{2}} = \frac {1}{1-x^{2}}
\end{align}
Integration yields:
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \int \frac{dx}{1-x^{2}} = \frac{1}{2} \, \int \left(\frac{1}{1-x} + \frac{1}{1+x} \right) dx \\ 
&= \frac{1}{2} \, \left[\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)\right] + C \\
&= \frac{\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)}{2} + C
\end{align}
and for $x=0$ we have $f(0) = 0$ so we get $C=0$.

Hence our answer is:
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{{x}^{n+1}}{n+1} \, P_{n}(x)} = \frac{1}{2} \, \ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$$

Comment: great! But I think your reccurence relation might be wrong. Maybe an error with the summation index ?

Comment: I don't think it is wrong, numerical approach agrees(try for multiple values of $x$ and compare you'll see ti's correct)

Comment: @Dominique Note that $\frac{\ln{(\frac{1+x}{1-x})}}{2} = arctanh(x)$

Comment: yes with the difference that you have $n+1$ as index on your last term while wikipedia has $n-1$. That was also the reason I was thinking of summation indices because the $n-1$ is only possible when you sum from $n=1$, not $n=0$. And indeed I saw that de logarithm and arctangent coincide :).

Comment: I got the recurrence relation from wikipedia(I will eventully prove it if you're still not conviced) so I don't think there's anything wrong, and there's not coincidence all the inverse hyperbolic functions are written in terms of logarithms ;)

Comment: What I am trying to say is that the relation on Wikipedia (and every other source that I consulted) reads $(x^2-1)P_n(x)=nxP_n(x)-nP_{n-1}(x)$. You turn out to have a $n+1$ where the relation has an $n-1$ and a different sign. That's the source of my confusion.

Comment: Since I didn't know anything about legendre Polynomials I typed the function in wolframalpha and it gave me its derivative which is the one I used. For your confusion I understand, you saw the recurrence relation not its derivative

Comment: I should indeed have looked at Wolfram in stead of wikipedia. The reccurence relation and derivative look so alike !

Comment: @Dominique Are you convinced now? ^^

Comment: I didn't check the relation for the derivative, but I'll just accept it for what it is :p. The solution fits with numerics anyway.

Comment: But don't worry I'll try to prove it

Answer (score 4):

While the other response is a good exercise in exploiting recurrence relations, a much more direct route is provided by the technique of summing under the integral which converts the series into an integral of the generating function:

$$\begin{align}
f{\left(x\right)}
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}P_{n}{\left(x\right)}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P_{n}{\left(x\right)}\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{d}t\,t^{n}\\
&=\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{d}t\,\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}t^{n}P_{n}{\left(x\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2xt+t^2}}\\
&=\int_{-x}^{\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}-1}{x}}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{2}{1-u^2};~~~\small{\left[\sqrt{1-2xt+t^2}=tu+1\right]}\\
&=2\int_{\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}}^{x}\frac{\mathrm{d}w}{1-w^2};~~~\small{\left[-u=w\right]}\\
&=2\operatorname{arctanh}{\left(x\right)}-2\operatorname{arctanh}{\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}\right)}\\
&=\operatorname{arctanh}{\left(x\right)}.\blacksquare\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Beautiful method +1